# Why is xception_71 inference time faster than that of xception_65 in deeplab?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, deeplab

I'm doing inference for semantic segmentation using pretrained (on cityscapes dataset) [DeepLab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) models based on xception_65 and xception_71 architectures. I've observed that:

1. xception_65 is better in creating segmentation masks compared to xception_71.
2. xception_71 is significantly faster than xception_65.

As xception_71 has 71 layers, which is more than the number of layers in xception_65 (65 layers), shouldn't it has higher inference time OR am I wrong somewhere?

(the number of blocks in [xception_65](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/core/xception.py#L591) are fewer compared to that in [xception_71](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/core/xception.py#L658))

You can check the code to reproduce the result at [colab:segmentation_deeplab.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G7Z2iTN6phcwtvzvBah3_x879wFWrg3s).

```
%%time

print('Model:', MODEL_NAME)
seg_map = MODEL.run(original_im)
```

**xception_65**

> Model: xception65_cityscapes_trainfine
>   CPU times: user 1.08 s, sys: 815 ms, total: 1.89 s
>   Wall time: 1.71 s

**xception_71**

> Model: xception71_cityscapes_trainfine
>   CPU times: user 146 ms, sys: 28 ms, total: 174 ms
>   Wall time: 649 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your notebook:

```
_DOWNLOAD_URL_PREFIX = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/'
_MODEL_URLS = {
    'xception65_cityscapes_trainfine':
        'deeplabv3_cityscapes_train_2018_02_06.tar.gz',
    'xception71_cityscapes_trainfine':
        'deeplab_cityscapes_xception71_trainfine_2018_09_08.tar.gz',
}
```

Note how the `exception65` links to a `deeplabv3` `tag.gz` but `xeception71` links to a vanilla `deeplab` `tar.gz`

Deeplab is a [whole series of models](https://towardsdatascience.com/review-deeplabv3-atrous-convolution-semantic-segmentation-6d818bfd1d74). Your `exception65` is a smaller backbone, under a newer more powerful segmenter, that's why it performs better.

---

To confirm the contents of the models try this (from [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks), [2](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/graph_pb2tb.py)):

```
%load_ext tensorboard

def graph_to_tensorboard(graph, out_dir):
  with tf.Session():
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(out_dir)
    train_writer.add_graph(graph)


graph_to_tensorboard(MODEL.graph, out_dir="logs")

%tensorboard --logdir logs
```